# jQuery ajax .done() function fired too early?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok here is a problem I am fighting with. I have this code (simplyfied):

```js
var initializeZasilkovna = function () {
  // Initialize object
  window.packetery.initialize();
};

// Check if the object doesnt exist
if (!window.packetery) {
  // It doesnt exists. Download it.
  $.ajax({
    url: document.location.protocol + "//www.zasilkovna.cz/api/v2/4854erws856w4efs/branch.js",
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true
  }).done(function () {
    // After download is complete initialize it.
    initializeZasilkovna();
  });
} else {
  // It exists only initialize it.
  initializeZasilkovna();
}
```

This ends up with an error "window.packetery" is undefined.

The thing is I want to load remote script on some event because it is too large. After its downloaded I want to call the function that inicializes it.

The problem is .done() function doesn't wait for the script to be fully loaded and fires initialisation too early. Is'n the .done() function supposed to wait? When I add setTimeout there it works properly. What could be wrong guys?

The funny thing is that I have the same piece of code on front-end and works properly. I haven't figured out what is wrong. Any advice appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: create a setInterval check that repeatedly checks for it to exist, once per, say, 100ms after the ajax request is complete. clear the interval once it's available. Not the cleanest solution, but it works every time in every browser.

Comment: @KevinB, no it does not work if the connection (mobile) or website is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [in the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) (em mine):

> Success Callback
>
> The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but **not
>   necessarily executed**.

AFAIK there's no way to **guarantee** that the script has been executed other than adding your callback to the script itself.

The common workaround is to use `setTimeout(initializeZasilkovna, 0)` though even this isn't 100% foolproof, it's up to the browser's JS engine to honour it.

Comment: That emphasis really *should* be in the original document.  Glad you caught that small line buried halfway down the page, it completely changes the expected behavior of the function.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a `success` that holds a function for callback

```
$.ajax({
    url:...
    ....
    success: function(res){
        //callback
    }
 });
```